# php.d/*.ini not overriding php.ini in PHP 5.5

Tags: php, php.ini, elastic-beanstalk

My `/etc/php.ini` has the following configuration:

```
upload_max_filesize = 2M
post_max_size = 32M
```

And `/etc/php.d/app.ini` contains:

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
```

With PHP 5.4, PHP was giving precedence to the app.ini values over the ones from php.ini; however, since I switched to PHP 5.5, they're not taking precedence anymore:

```
# php -r "echo ini_get('upload_max_filesize');"
2M
```

The `app.ini` file looks successfully parsed by PHP:

```
# php --ini
...
/etc/php-5.5.d/app.ini,
...
```

(`/etc/php.d` is a symlink to `/etc/php-5.5.d`)

**How can I force php.d ini files to take precedence over php.ini?**

*If that makes any difference, I'm using the AWS Elastic Beanstalk container for PHP 5.5.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the reason, which is indeed *specific to the Elastic Beanstalk container for PHP 5.5*.

For some obscure reason, the AWS team chose to move `php.ini` from its original location in `/etc/php.ini` to `/etc/php.d/php.ini`.

Because the files in `php.d` are processed in alphabetical order, my `app.ini` was now processed **before** `php.ini`, and was thus overridden.

I have opened [a thread on the AWS forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=143745), to ask AWS if they would consider moving `php.ini` back to its original location.

In the meantime, the solution is simply to **rename the file to make it appear after php.ini**, in my case renaming to `zapp.ini` did the trick.